# Can I still join the Dark Brotherhood if I've already destroyed it?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

My cousin has Skyrim and he says that you can join the dark brotherhood after destroying it. Is this the case? If so, how would one do it?

Comment: Unless you use the Command Console, no.

Answer (score 8):

No. You can't join something that doesn't exist anymore. In fact the choice to destroy the Dark Brotherhood is made when asked to join them. It's one or the other, not both.